# Switching backgrounds, while switching text

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, getelementbyid

I was able to make the text loop infinitely and the body color change once:

```
<?php?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
header{background-color:orange;}
#color1{background-color:red;}
#color2{background-color:green;}
#color3{background-color:blue;}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var flip = (function() {
    var flip = ['_addText1','_addText2','_addText3'];
    var count = -1;
    return function() {
        return flip[++count % flip.length];
    }
}());
-->
</script>


<body id="color1">

<header onclick="document.getElementById('click').innerHTML = flip(); document.getElementById('color1').setAttribute('id', 'color2');">
    <h1>StaticText<a id="click">_ThisWillChange</a></h1>
    <p>Click anywhere in the header to change the text above.<br />
       This will also change the body color.</p>
</header>

</body>
<?php?>
```

The first problem is; if I add more color changes to the 'onclick' attribute it stops working all together. Basically I want the color to loop with the text:

```
document.getElementById('color2').setAttribute('id', 'color3');
document.getElementById('color3').setAttribute('id', 'color1');
```

The second problem is that I'm not really 'fluent' in javascript. I'm actually lucky I figured out this much to be honest.

I'm sure there's a way to put it all into the javascript (to keep my HTML clean), but I don't know how.

Any help would be most appreciated! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to **change the id** of the element if you are so keen to set the color.

You can just the class on the body element which should get the work done for you.

Secondly it's a bad practice to bind events inline. Use javascript to bind the events as well.

```
<body id="color1" class="color1">
```

This is one way of writing the code.

**Code**

```
var header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];

header.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var body = document.getElementById('color1');
    document.getElementById('click').innerHTML = flip("text");
    body.className = flip("color");
});


var flip = (function () {
    var flip = ['_addText1', '_addText2', '_addText3'],
        colors = ["color1", "color2", "color3"];
    var count = -1,
        colorCount = -1;
    return function (arg) {
        if(arg === 'text')
            return flip[++count % flip.length];
        if(arg === 'color')
            return colors[++colorCount % colors.length];
    }
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<body id="color1" class="color0">
    <header>
         <h1>StaticText<a id="click">_ThisWillChange</a></h1>

        <p>Click anywhere in the header to change the text above.
            <br />This will also change the body color.</p>
    </header>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    background-color:orange;
}
.color0 {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.color1 {
    background-color:red;
}
.color2 {
    background-color:green;
}
.color3 {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fpdU/1/)**

Comment: Sometimes I think I just make more work for myself...lol

Thanks for the help that's awesome. Plus I'm not too great at js just yet.

Comment: @MatrixNinja..It's a learning process you know !! Glad to have helped:)