# Remove single attribute from element multiple times using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

Here's my code so far:

```
<script src="http://.../jquery/1.7.1/..."></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').removeAttr('style');
});
</script>
```

---

```
<form>
    <tr><td>
    <textarea name="Comment" cols="18" rows="4" style=""></textarea>
    </td></tr>
</form>
```

I put a blank `style` tag first to see if it works, which it does, but using `.ready` only removes it initially.

When you drag the corner of the `textarea` to enlarge it, it produces a new `style="xyz"`

**My question is:** How can I repeat this function, automatically, every time the attribute `style="xyz"` shows up? Basically resetting it back to the default `cols="18" rows="4"` size I specified.

(Sorry if this might be a simple answer, but I'm not very good with js/jQ just yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for JS to do that, just

```
<textarea name="Comment" cols="18" rows="4" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

Comment: oh snap...I've been so involved with jQuery lately I totally forgot about that! Thanks, haha!

Comment: can you help me with another question I had?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151776/switching-backgrounds-while-switching-text

Answer (score 2):

I think @gustavohenke gave you a good tip.
Nonetheless, if you want to do it with javascript you have to write a hook that execute a function (in your case remove the attribute) each time the textarea is resized.

To accomplish so, have a look at [Resize event for textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea)

Comment: can you help me with another question i had?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151776/switching-backgrounds-while-switching-text